# How to remove part of content in div

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am using DataTables, and it is producing something like this, e.g a input inside the label element:

```
<label>
    Search:
    <input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="example">
</label>
```

What I want to do is to remove the text Search: inside the label, **but I dont want to remove the input**, could someone point me in the right direction here?
Maybe it could be done with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the initialisation with a `"language"` parameter:

```
element.DataTable({
  "language": {
    "search": ""
  }
});
```

This is a hack, as in, `language` is a parameter to change the Search String for a particular language. When we give an empty value for that, it doesn't show the search text there. Problem solved.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#example").DataTable({
    "language": {
      "search": ""
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jq-2.2.4/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jq-2.2.4/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2012/11/27</td>
      <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2010/06/09</td>
      <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2009/04/10</td>
      <td>$237,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/10/13</td>
      <td>$132,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dai Rios</td>
      <td>Personnel Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>2012/09/26</td>
      <td>$217,500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `$(function() {`  has no meaning what so ever. And I would not call it a "hack" since it is how you *should* change language strings in dataTables.

Comment: @davidkonrad Did you even understand what I called hack? I gave a reasoning as well. Not sure why you didn't understand. You are changing the language string - That's a hack! Not the `$(function () {`! `:(` And why do you say, it has no meaning whatsoever? It's a short hand version of `$(document).ready(function () {})` - Do you know why it is used?

Comment: If you *need* `$(function() {` or similar you either have a rare complex setup or have constructed the webpage in a inexpedient way. Most of the  usage is [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) and needless in an answer when there is no obvious reason. If it is a "hack" to set an attribute on a initialization literal as it is intended to be set, then everything is a hack :) EOD.

Comment: @davidkonrad Gotcha, now I understand what you are telling. Well, ... ha ha. No comments. All my answers have full code in them.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

**In dataTable:**

**Remove Search Box:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable( {      
         "searching": false 
    });
});
```

**Remove Search Label:**

```
$("#dataTable").dataTable({
   "language": { "search": "" }
});
```

Comment: The requirement was not to remove the input. From the question: *but i dont want to remove the input*. And your snippet doesn't seem to work.